# Publishing html table on Google Site

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api

I have a html table which is updated very often. Currently we copy and paste the html code to the Google Site as embedded code. That works, but is time consuming and not each editor have the skills to do that.

Now I thought it should be possible to use embed url, but that will not work because the source  file is located on a Google Drive ==> only the source code will be shown.

A colleague told me that I can use Google Apps Script (GAS), but it works only when the html table is directly in GAS. That will not work for same reasons as before.
Therefore I tried to get the file, but I receive the the error message

> Exception: No HTML file named `<style type="text/css">`

Here my code

```
function doGet() {
  //getting html file will not work ==>  Exception: No HTML file named
  var html = DriveApp.getFileById("12fozYxDoK-RDcUIf0Cxpq7Cz8mfdXNjy").getBlob().getDataAsString();
   //html file saved as txt ==> Exception: No HTML file named
  var txt = DriveApp.getFileById("1Ekiwc7lJPuaelMcSJ9hRtvTsunJ8h1XF").getBlob().getDataAsString();

  //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(html);
  //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(txt);
  
  //works only with embedded html file
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('DocumentTable');
}
```

What can I do to show the html table from the Google Drive file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73759203/how-can-i-display-in-my-google-site-a-count-of-rows-in-my-google-sheet-having-a/73759894#73759894

Answer (score 2):

I figures out how it works:

```
function doGet() {
  var html = DriveApp.getFileById("12fozYxDoK-RDcUIf0Cxpq7Cz8mfdXNjy").getBlob();

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}
```